# Stop Apple Notes from cutting off handwritten text

Tags: pdf, notes.app, ipados

When hand writing notes in Apple Notes, it is very easy to cut off notes across pages when exporting the note. This is because dividers between pages aren't shown as they are in Notability or GoodNotes, making it easy to write over a page boundary and cut off the note when exporting the note.

Is there any way to export the note as a continuous PDF (a la OneNote) so that text doesn't get cut off, or show page dividers in the Notes app so that the user is aware of where the page divisions are?

Comment: Do you have a Mac computer? I know your quesion was referring to an iPad but there is an easy solution if you have a Mac computer.

Comment: A Mac-based solution is not completely ideal but it would definitely work

Comment: Funny thing is, I was going to say go with OneNote.  Every time I tried looking at the native Notes app, I kept going back to OneNote because it just did everything better. It's also cross platform so....

Comment: OneNote is nice, but IIRC it exports as a massive sheet which isn't that nice for printing. I prefer Notability/GoodNotes since they have actual pages :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac and an iPhone on same network the Notes on one device shows up on other.  So your notes should show up on your Mac and handwritten notes will appear as well. There is an option in Notes on a Mac to export selected note as a PDF.  When I tried this the Note apeared on 2 pages in the PDF and all the info was there.

Comment: Great idea! The quality seems to be very low though.

Answer (score 1):

Often times the "Export as PDF" option still will cut off the ends of my drawing segments of handwritten notes, as oppose to moving the drawings to the next page, even though I chunk them out as half-iPad screen-sized drawing canvases, and divide consecutive drawings with hyphens "-". I have found using this chunking and dividing method, if I instead "Print" and then "Save as PDF" from the print menu I will get a PDF that does not cut off my handwritten drawing and instead moves that drawing to the next page.