# Export handwritten note from Apple Note on iPad to PDF

Tags: ipad, pdf, notes.app

I am using an iPad for taking handwritten notes. My notes also contain some images I've cut and pasted from the screen capture feature on the iPad.

I'd simply like to export my notes to PDF to share them.

As noted in this [old post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/403031/stop-apple-notes-from-cutting-off-handwritten-text), exporting a note from iPad "cuts off" the handwritten text across pages.

A proposed solution is to print the note from Notes.  This seems to work ok for simple handwritten notes.

However, if the note contains an image, the result is extremely weird: the handwritten text is flipped both horizontally and vertically. Leonardo da Vinci would probably love this, but I find it very annoying. In addition, the handwritten text below an image is moved to the next page and it often gets cut off anyway.

Does this happen to anyone else?

Is there a reasonable workaround? I'd be happy even with a PDF containing a single very long page (kind of like a "scroll").

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issues. Exporting handwritten notes from ipad to pdf only exports one page (cuts off the rest). Exporting pdf notes with mixture of handwritten notes and photos does the weird inversion thing.

My labourious workaround is to share the note as a picture (.png).

Comment: I did some minor editing to your answer so that it wouldn’t get flagged as a non-answer.  Keep in mind that this isn’t a forum thread and answers are for posts that answer the question being asked. Take a few moments to view the [tour] so you can get the best experience from this site.  Oh, and Welcome!